# I need help getting a <div> to refresh on form submit

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have looked all over stack, and googled the crap out of it, but everytime I come across something I only come across snippets and I cannot find the full code, how can I get a div to reload on form submit?

this is the div I want to refresh

```
 <div id="accsettings">
<?php require_once('￼profileform.php'); ?>
</div>
```

this is the form

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?username=' . $user_name; ?>">
```

Thanks

I need it to refresh on submit so that it shows the affect the player had on their profile

(by showing their comment and that they increased their rep on the webpage by +1 and removing the textfields/submit form, all that is already taken care of, I just need it to refresh on submit)

Comment: Do you want the content to update without reloading the entire page, or  do you need the div's content to update without reloading the page? The former requires zero JavaScript whereas the latter requires at least some jQuery/AJAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("form").on('submit', function (e) {
   $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize() + '&submit=TRUE').done(
      function ()  {
         $("#accsettings").load('profileform.php');
      }
   );

   e.preventDefault();
});
```

What this will do is an ajax load of `profileform.php` into the contents of the `#accsettings` div.  This assumes that your form submission properly updates the output of `profileform.php` and is done via ajax (I see no evidence of that in your code currently, though).

Comment: Where do I put that, in <script></script>? and that will do it on form submit?

Comment: Show me the rest of your JS code in your question and I can tell you where to put it

Comment: I have 0 JS code, that's the thing I'm currently seeking haha

Comment: @user1976501 if your form submits and refreshes the whole page, shouldn't the `profileform.php` code be loaded automatically?

Comment: Yeah, but do I just do, <script> *the code you typed* </script> and that's fine?

Comment: @user1976501 no.  If it's already working, then why are you even asking a question?  What's happening and what's your desired result?

Comment: http://imgur.com/OXVdgGg this is what's happening when I hit submit, everything in the black box should be gone, but it's there until I manually hit refresh at the top of the page

Comment: What's the name of you submit? You could do something like `if (!isset($_POST['submitButtonName'])) { require_once('￼profileform.php');}`

Comment: But does the page refresh when you hit "Submit?"  If not then there has to be some JavaScript code that's submitting the page.

Comment: I have ZERO javascript on my page, the extent of my javascript on my page is <script>$("accsettings").load('profile.php');</script> that is it, my page does refresh, but the div contents does not for some reason until I refresh the page manually

Comment: @user1976501 that's probably because whatever php code you have that does the form processing is *after* when you include `profileform.php`, which is incorrect.  You really need to change your setup, but there is another way to do it via ajax (I'll update my answer).

Comment: @ExplosionPills I copy and pasted exactly that, but it didn't cause a refresh on submit.

Comment: @user1976501 do you have a link to your page by any chance?  Any JavaScript errors?  When the form submits, the page shouldn't refresh at all.

Comment: Just register an acc (it's quick) and then click the link I just linked you, write a comment on that page, and click submit, you'll see the page refreshes and the text field is still there, then click the link again, and you'll see how it should look @ExplosionPills

Comment: @user1976501 you're not loading jQuery on the page.  Include the jQuery script *before* the calls to `$`, and move that stuff to right before `</body>`

Comment: How do I do that? @ExplosionPills and can you recommend a good book to learn jQuery / jSon / JS?

Comment: @ExplosionPills Cause I'm not sure how

Comment: @user1976501 add this before `</body>` (and then the other script code after it): `<script type=text/javascript src=//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js></script>`

Comment: @ExplosionPills I did just that, but the entire <div> is now gone when submit is pressed, is that how you intended it? I just wanted it to refresh. You know how when you click edit on this page, it just instantly refreshes that spot with a textfield and when you click save, it goes away, I want it similar to that

Comment: @user1976501 no not really .. After you submit what happens when you go to `profileform.php` directly?  Because that's what should be loaded into the div

Comment: @ExplosionPills can't go directly to profileform.php it's reliant on it's embodying viewprofile.php for it's mysqli_connect and what not

Comment: @user1976501 oh .. in that case try `$("#accsetting").load('viewprofile.php #Some-Id-Containing-Just-profileform.php-data");`

Comment: @ExplosionPills sorry you lost me on #Some-Id-Containing-Just-profileform.php-data", you mean like #accsettings? would it make it easier for you to help me if I took it out of profileform.php and just included it in viewprofile instead of having a separate file just for it?

Comment: Yeah I guess #accsettings would work as a substitute for that; I think you can manage to do the rest on your own and learn from the experience

Comment: @ExplosionPills I'll mark you  as answered for all your help, but could you recommend a good book for learning JS / JSON / JQUERY?

Comment: @user1976501 I can't .. you can check out O'Reilly Media as they have some very good books on all kinds of programming topics, but I've actually never ready a jQuery book

Answer (score 1):

What's the name of you submit button? If it were `submit`, you could do something like:

```
<div id="accsettings">
<?php if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) { require_once('￼profileform.php');} else {echo '&nbsp';} ?>
</div>
```

This assumes that the form submits to the current page.

Comment: The form's `action` is `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` so the form redirects to the page the form is already on. This method seems the most easy and accurate. +1

Comment: @DouglasA.Crosby +1 Yeah the only reason I added that bottom sentence was to serve as a disclaimer, just making sure to clarify. :)

Comment: This would work, the only thing is, the div doesn't show at all after I hit submit, but I need it to show cause it should turn from this > imgur.com/OXVdgGg to this > http://imgur.com/yXgXUdb

Comment: @user1976501 Good point, if the `div` is empty then it could cause other potential problems. I added the HTML entity for a space which should keep the `div` in tact and not affect flow (such as `floats`, etc).

Comment: If the empty div causes problems, you could put it all inside the if brackets. `if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) { echo "<div id='accsettings'>"; require_once('￼profileform.php'); echo "</div>"; }`

Comment: In instances like this I tend to lean towards the space character, if only because styling other elements could depend on a `div` in my layout. So I prefer to build with content and substitute space to avoid having to create exceptions.

Comment: I see what you're getting at, but I think you are a little confused as to what I want, I want that to appear no matter what, in a nutshell, what that form does, is it puts in a value in the table, which is then returned whenever the user that submitted the review looks at that account again, he will no longer see the text field and be able to write another comment, instead that is gone and all he see's is a list of the comments on the players profile, with your code, he could simply type ?username="w/e" and keep writing comments + giving points to his profile, all this code is already taken

Comment: care of by my php code in profileform, I just want the profileform to refresh when the player hits submit, so they no longer see the textfield or submit button right when they hit submit @DouglasA.Crosby

Comment: You are right, I don't understand what you are asking. Still don't, your OP states: 'removing the textfields/submit form' which I believe I have shown, assuming that `￼profileform.php` is the form and only the form. Seems to me like you need what I have above as well as some additional code at the beginning of the page pulling information submitted to the database and displaying if the `$_POST` is set, etc.

Comment: @user1976501 let me make some assumptions here and please correct me as needed. `profileform.php` displays the entire form and when the user submits that form (by submitting a comment), the form must not allow them to submit a second comment for that page/blog/etc - even after they leave the site and come back. For this, you need more than JS - you need to actually update the user's profile in the database on submit, or check if they've posted before when you first display `profileform.php` and display the form accordingly there.

Comment: You'll get into your need for jQuery when you want to update the page's content without reloading the entire page on form submit (a question I asked of your original post). jQuery/AJAX is not used to do actual database modifications (submitting the comment, updating profiles, etc) - it's used simply to call php scripts which then do the work (it also updates content on the page, etc but that's beyond my point).

Comment: I have done exactly that @DouglasA.Crosby I updated the query in the database with ifs and sql to make it so anybody that comments, can't comment again, but when they add a comment, this only takes affect if the page is manually refreshed (if they leave, logout and comeback, refresh the page) they will not be able to comment, but when they add that first initial comment the webpage is not refreshed properly, the text field is still there, but if they were to manually refresh the page, it would be gone, that is why I want it to refresh

Comment: Refresh doesn't POST unless the last call to the page was a POST and the user (upon refresh) informed the browser to re-submit the data (which can simply be resolved in SQL and a header re-direct), therefore my solution was to only remove the form if POST was called.

Comment: @user1976501 "when they add that first initial comment the webpage is not refreshed properly" - this is the problem then. The basic process should go: 1) Load page with text fields, 2) User fills out the text and submits the form, 3) The form is sent to the PHP file to update the database - the page refreshes here (unless you add jQuery but we'll say not for now), and 4) The page no longer displays the text field.

Comment: Wait.. if it displays correctly after refresh.. and the form is submitted to the same page the form is on.. It's a simple ordering issue. Move the code that updates the database (inserts the comment, does whatever else on form submit) above/before the form in the PHP file. This leaves the part where the form is actually displayed beneath/after the updates have been made.